# Disable default home launcher

Tags: android, homescreen

I'm building a home screen application for android and I'd like to disable (temporary) the default home screen (TwLauncher) or whatever app is running.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable other homescreens, but you can register your app as a homescreen by adding the appropriate intent-filters to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="Home"  
        android:theme="@style/Theme"  
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"  
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

Different homescreens can exists concurrently, the user ultimately decides which homescreen he wants to set as his default homescreen *manually*.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look to this sample code on the official website : [Home app sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter that problem here is the solution go to preferences of your default launcher look for exit for ex: exit go launcher ex then ok. This will disable the default.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)